# Angular2 v.2.3 - Accessing HTML5 validation attributes for reactive forms without specifying attributes in template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So I'm trying to write a directive to add validation messages onto elements of a reactive form.

Suppose I have the following component template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls['myText']" my-validation-messages>
</form>
```

And the following component logic:

```
@Component({
    // Declarations go here...
})
class MyComponent {
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            "myText": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[abc]*"), Validators.minLength(10)]
        });
    }
}
```

And the following directive logic:

```
@Directive({
    selector: ["my-validation-messages"]
})
export class MyValidationMessagesDirective {
    @Input() formControl: FormControl;
    element: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor(private elm: ElementRef) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }

    ngOnInit(): {
        this.element = this.elm.nativeElement;
    }

    @HostListener("input") onInput(): {
        if (!this.formControl.pristine && !this.formControl.valid) {
            // Make validation message here.
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that if I put the pattern and minLength attributes in the template instead of the component, I can get the actual pattern and minLength values in the directive via this.element.pattern and this.element.minLength. And if I leave them out of the template, the accessors return null as expected. (This also applies to the other validator attributes, e.g.: required and min.)

So in the directive, can I use anything in formControl to get the actual pattern and minLength values to form specific validation messages (e.g.: "This field can only accept a's, b's, or c's." and "You need to type more than 10 characters.")? Or do I have to specify them in the template?

**Edit:**

Partial answer found. All form controls have this object (formControl.errors) that basically says why the control is invalid. But referencing formControl.errors is limited in the following ways:

1) The validator functions attached to the form control have to explicitly include the threshold values in their return object. The Angular team has already done this for required, minLength, maxLength and pattern, and any custom validator functions would have to be designed similarly.

```
  /**
   * minLength validator straight from @angular/forms/src/validators.ts.
   * Note the 'requiredLength' property.
   */
  static minLength(minLength: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      ...
      return length < minLength ?
          {'minlength': {'requiredLength': minLength, 'actualLength': length}} :
          null;
    };
}
```

2) formControl.errors only gets built when the form control is invalid, and is null otherwise. In my case, I'm fine with that since I only want the attribute values at that time, but it might be a problem if I wanted to do something with them at any other time; e.g. if I wanted to give the element a placeholder that describes the field's expected value.

```
ngOnInit(): {
    this.element = this.elm.nativeElement;
    // this.formControl.errors = null;
}

@HostListener("input") onInput(): {
    if (!this.formControl.pristine && !this.formControl.valid) {
        // this.formControl.errors = {[key: string]: any};
        let errors = "";
        for (let reason in this.control.errors) {
            errors += this.createValidationMessage(reason) + "/n";
        }
    }
}

createValidationMessage(reason: string): string {
    switch(reason) {
        case "minlength":
            let minLength = this.formControl.errors['minlength']['requiredLength'];
            return "You need to type more than " + minLength + " characters.";
        ...
        case "required":
            return "Please enter something into the field.";
        /* The case names and how the attribute is referenced will depend on the validator 
         * function implementation; e.g. required returns just {required: true}, but minLength 
         * returns {requiredLength: X, actualLength: Y}.
         */
    }
}
```

The first limitation just requires a design choice, but is there something I can do about the second one? (i.e.: Is there anything in formControl that will always be available to pull the attribute values from? Again, without specifying them in the template.)